# How to prove this logical equivalence using laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

im trying to solve this logical equation

p≡((p∧∼q)→q)→p
i know i have to solve for the right side and im pretty certain the final step must be the absorption law 10). But the ∼q is bugging me

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> im pretty certain the final step must be the absorption law 10). But the ∼q is bugging me

Yes it is, but there is no reason to be bugged.

The relevant absorption law is that: for *any* predicates $A$ and $B$ , we have:  $((A\land B)\lor A)\equiv A$ .

Just substitute $p$ for $A$ and ${\sim}q$ for $B$ . Since the law works for *any* $A,B$, it shall work for those too.

Answer (score 0):

One key technique here is to use other sentence to rephrase $a \to b$.

It is known that $a \to b$ is false only if $a$ is true and $b$ is false.

Using the table of truth or other method should help you find the way to rephrase it.

Actually, in solving this problem, I have not used the absorption law. What I use is $(a \wedge b) \lor (a \wedge \lnot b) \equiv a $